# convert select to select_tag in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, select, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to convert select to select_tag of this statement:

```
<%= select "invoice_product_code",
    @invoice_product_array.each_with_index.map {
        |jsondata, index| 
            [jsondata["invoice_product_code"],
            index]}, 
            {:selected => item["invoice_product_code"]},
            :style => "width:110px"

        %>
```

Bare in mind,

- I want to define each the option value and option text from the array
- selected option
- style

just like the above.

this is the generated HTML:

```
 <select id="invoice_product_code_invoice_product_code" name="invoice_product_code[invoice_product_code]" style="width:110px"><option value="0">INVPRODA</option>
 <option value="1">INVPRODB</option>
 <option selected="selected" value="2">INVPRODC</option>
 <option value="3">INVPRODD</option>
 <option value="4">INVPRODE</option>
 <option value="5">INVPRODF</option>
 <option value="6">INVPRODG</option></select>
```

I have a feeling its impossible. Cant find a suitable example from the API http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag

This didnt work:

```
 <%= select_tag "invoice_product_code",  
    @invoice_product_array.each_with_index.map {
        |jsondata, index| 
            [jsondata["invoice_product_code"],
            index]} 


        %>
```

And this didnt work:
Its in correct because value and display text is a json string instead of a particular key value from the array item.

```
        <%= select_tag "invoice_product_code",  
            options_for_select(@invoice_product_array)

        %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`options_for_select` takes an extra argument to specify the selected value and each option can have HTML attributes as the last element.

```
<%= select_tag "invoice_product_code", options_for_select(  
  @invoice_product_array.each_with_index.map {
    |jsondata, index| 
      [jsondata["invoice_product_code"],
      index,
      style: 'width: 110px;']},
  item["invoice_product_code"])
%>
```